# What is the ComplexityFunction used by FullSimplify in Mathematica 12?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I was surprised to see `FullSimplify` make my expressions numerically unstable. The result can be summarized below:

```
FullSimplify[-E^-t, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount] (* -E^-t *)
FullSimplify[-E^-t] (* -Cosh[t]+Sinh[t] *)
```

Last time I dove deep into Mathematica, `LeafCount` was the default complexity measure, but this seems to have changed sometime in the last 10 years...what is the new heuristic?

Comment: Both of them have ``LeafCount`` 7. In the documentation for ``ComplexityFunction`` you can read: *With the default setting ``ComplexityFunction->Automatic``, forms are ranked primarily according to their LeafCount, **with corrections** to treat integers with more digits as more complex.* This is probably the reason why ``Automatic`` converges to one solution and ``LeafCount`` to another.

Comment: [SimplifyCount:ComplexityFunction >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)?

Comment: ``FullSimplify[-E^-t, ComplexityFunction -> Simplify`SimplifyCount]``